# Is there any way of finding inverse without "switching"?

Tags: inverse-function

I have seen a lot of articles and books teaching how to find an inverse of a function by 'switching' $x$ and $y$ and solve for $y$ variables. My understanding of an inverse function is that it undoes whatever the function being given do, i.e. $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. With this, I want to find the inverse of a function without using the 'switching of $x$ and $y$' since I can't find the reason why the 'switching of $x$ and $y$' works. Is there any other approach?

Comment: I totally agree with you. I use to say : "solve" for $x$ the equation $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(y)$ is the inverse.